# Place focus on input select option

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following html:

```
<select id="selectBox"  name ="plus<?php echo $k; ?>">
        <option  value =" "></option>
        <option  value ="1">1</option>
        <option  value ="2">2</option>
```

and this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
   $("#selectBox option:eq(1)").attr("selected","selected");
</script>
```

the above works but I need to pass a php variable for eq(1).  I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var x = <?php echo $_POST['cnt']; ?>;   
   $("#selectBox option:eq(x)").attr("selected","selected");
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show us what php generates? e.g. the html that it spits out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass **x** as variable, not some string. Doing so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var x = <?php echo $_POST['cnt']; ?>;   
   $("#selectBox option:eq(" + x + ")").attr("selected","selected");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the following works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$("#selectBox option:eq("+<?php echo $_POST['num_res'];?>+")").attr("selected","selected");
</script>>
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?